# Removing lines containing not alphabetic characters. [Notepad++ / Regex]

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm compiling a dictionary file from a bunch of different smaller dictionary files. The compiled list in the format:

```
apple
banana
carrot
```

But some of the files contain weird unicode characters, comments, and spaces. I want to completely remove any lines that contain any non-alphabetic characters. So for a list like this:

```
apple
Ϥ
#comment
banana carrot
zeta
```

Would become:

```
apple
zeta
```

What would be the best way to do this?

**Edit: This includes removing blank lines.**

Comment: Perhaps, `^(?![a-zA-Z]+(?:\R|\z)).*\R*`? or `^.*[^a-zA-Z\r].*\R*`

Comment: Neither of those work

Comment: Sorry, then the question is too unclear. With both the regexps, I get the 2 `apple` and `zeta` items left.

Comment: Yes, but each line needs to be counted separately.

Comment: Which language do you intend to use? Personally, I think python would be best.

Comment: @JulianLachniet: Yeah, as I said, no idea what you mean by *each line needs to be counted separately*. Any more hidden requirements? See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I could do a Python script if it would be easier than Notepad++. What would be a fast script to do so?

Comment: Nevermind, the answer here works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to open the `Replace` window and fill it as follows:

[image]

you can then click on `Replace All`

If you want to **remove blank lines** repeat the same thing: Fill `Find what` by `^\s*` and keep `replace with` **empty**

Answer (score 0):

```
writeTo=open("newTable.txt","a")
for line in open("table.txt","r"):
    if(not line=="\n"): 
        use=True
        for char in line.replace("\n",""):
            if(not char.isalnum() and not char==' '):
                use=False
                break
        if(use):
            writeTo.write(line)
writeTo.close()
```

Clarification: This is python code that requires the input directory to be table.txt and writes its output to newTable.txt